# How to make a bot check the amount of messages sent in a day with Discord.js

Tags: discord, bots

I know that it is currently impossible for a bot to check the Discord Search Filter thing; I am pretty sure the only way is to count the messages one by one.

I've seen people do this, but they done it with all the messages ever sent, not just messages sent in a day. So is there a Discord.js function or method I can use to clamp it to the confines of one day? I also don't need to check for specific users since I want every message sent on just one guild, not just from one user.

I am very new to the outside coding scene in general so in help/direction is highly appreciated.

I looked over posts on StackOverflow but none of them addresses my situation, neither have YouTube videos, nor what I have seen on the docs. I have seen functions like channel.history, but I don't know how to implement it and I don't think it would cover my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. It was relatively simple actually. It does come with some downsides however.
I had to get the time var date = new Date(); and getting the hours with date.getHours();. Once I did that it was as simple as client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {if(Hours == 24 [Midnight]) {Message_Count = 0} [Global variable set to zero beforehand] Message_Count++}. So the variable counts up by one everytime a message is created and when it hits midnight, it resets. However this means that if you turn off the bot at any point in time, the counter will reset back to zero. I'm sure there's a way you could avoid that with .json files and whatnot, but I'm satisfied the way it is.